# How can I detect if an user clicks on a banner ad on Admob in React Naive?

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, admob

I'm concerned about Admob click bombing where someone clicks on a banner too many times for Google to ban the account.
That's something that I've heard.
To prevent that, it seems like it's a better idea to implement the feature where if someone clicks on the banner too many times, then the app hide the ad for a while so that he couldn't click anymore.
To implement that feature, I think I need to know if someone clicks on it or not, like event lisner.

I did quite lot of research on it, but no luck. I couldn't find a way to do it.
(But it's a bit weird because if it's important, then I should be able to find info quite easily.)

By the way, I use Expo for creating apps.
And I'm using this npm 'react-native-google-mobile-ads'.

I have this code.

```
              <BannerAd
                unitId={BannerUnit}
                size={BannerAdSize.BANNER}
                requestOptions={{
                  requestNonPersonalizedAdsOnly: true,
                }}
              />
```

I'm also wondering how people prevent that.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think is possible. On web ads from google are displayed in a separate iframe and dues to security policies you can no have access to any iframe data.

I would suggest alternative methods, to detect invalid traffic and do not display ads on shady traffic.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).